# Overriding how a generic class based looks up an object from the URL arguments

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-rest-framework

My understanding is that generic class based views ultimately rely on a `pk` variable specified by the corresponding `urls.py` to perform a database lookup. In `urls.py` I specify the `pk`, then in the class-based view I just provide the queryset and serializer class.

Is there a way to keep the near DRY-ness of the generic view but override *only* how the class goes from a `pk` to an object or queryset? I know I could inherit from an APIView instead and provide the `get`, `post`, etc. methods myself, but then that's an awful lot more code. I want to keep using the inbuilt functionality of generics but just provide the mechanism to go from url arguments to an object or queryset.

I'm trying to allow objects to be specified in a url by their ordinality rather than their pk. So, `/foo/1` maps to `Foo.objects.all()[0]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the solution is to override `get_object` - I hadn't realise I could access the url parameters under the view class itself:

```
class Foo(generics.RetrieveDestroyAPIView):
    serializer_class = FooSerializer

    def get_object(self):
        return Foo.objects.all()[self.kwargs['foo_if_in_url'] - 1]
```